# Which is better to make a web application offline -application cache or service worker?

Tags: service-worker, html5-appcache, offline-mode, offline-browsing

I want to make my web application available even if network is not preset or when user is offline.

I searched about this and find two solution:
1) use Application cache
2) use Service worker

As service worker is in developing state and not supported by all browser so can not find this is a feasible according to my requirements.

On the other hand, application cache is about to deprecated(MDN site) from most of browser(still supporting in many browsers), I can not go with this solution too.

Please give some suggestion or correct me if I am wrong on above points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This book https://www.manning.com/books/progressive-web-apps recommends service workers.

Comment: @oscar but service worker isn't supported by safari and IE browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguring is correct. Currently service workers are not supported by all browser and I doesn't look like Safari will support it in the near future, but at least it appears on their [five year plan](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/FiveYearPlanFall2015).

You can still use application cache, even if it doesn't have all the features sw brings and even if it will be deprecated. It is possible to have a sw / application cache mix on your site.

You have to compare the benefits against the work/money you want to put in your site to make it work offline. If you have an existing site you can check your browser stats and then make a decision.

Comment: I am also thinking to use mix of both. Thanks.